# Splice is not working

Tags: c++, list, splice

I have the following code, the `splice` function in it is not working and not returning any result, and I don't know why. Help please.

The main idea is I need to take a range from a list and add it to another empty list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream       
    reader("list.txt");

    list < string > wholeSequenceVctr;
    list < string > sequenceVctr;
    list < string > subsequenceVctr (10);

    string line;
    if (reader.is_open()) {
        while (getline(reader, line)) {
            wholeSequenceVctr.push_back(line);
        }
    }// if

    sequenceVctr.insert(sequenceVctr.begin(), 
                        wholeSequenceVctr.begin(),
                        wholeSequenceVctr.end());

    list < string >::iterator from=sequenceVctr.begin();
    list < string >::iterator to=sequenceVctr.begin();
    advance(from,2);
    advance(to,4);

    subsequenceVctr.splice(subsequenceVctr.begin(),
                           sequenceVctr,
                           from,
                           to);

    //  printing section

    cout << "wholeSequenceVctr" << endl;
    list < string >::iterator i;
    for (i = wholeSequenceVctr.begin(); i != wholeSequenceVctr.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i;

    cout << endl << "sequenceVctr" << endl;
    list < string >::iterator j;
    for (j = sequenceVctr.begin(); j != sequenceVctr.end(); ++j)
        cout << *j;

    cout << endl << "SubsequenceVctr" << endl;
    list < string >::iterator k;
    for (k = subsequenceVctr.begin(); k != subsequenceVctr.end(); ++k)
        cout << *k;
}
```

---

Here is sample of `list.txt` file:

> CP52
>   CP74
>   CP24
>   CP404
>   CP3812
>   CP5069

Comment: Can you share a sample from the input format?

Comment: Are you certain you're not overlooking the fact that you do not print a '\n' character? I tried it with a small list.txt with a couple of characters and 4-5 lines and it does seem to work. I initially thought it wasn't printing anything as well, but it turned out that I just didn't notice the printed characters on the leftmost part of the bottom line of the terminal.

Comment: @ilim it is not printing problem, i try to debug but the list still empty after splice. also would you please try the updated code ?

Comment: See [here](http://ideone.com/eSI6NJ) for a working example. All I changed was feeding the input through standard input as this website does not accept input from other files. On my own device, though, it successfully reads from list.txt and prints the exact same thing you can see as the output at the link I provided.

Comment: @ilim . thank you very much everything is good now it works like magic. thanks again